# How to get AngularJS routing to maintain state?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm getting up to speed with AngularJS routing and have created this example which works.

However, I understood that if on page "home" I type in a text into the input box, then click on page "about" and then come back to "home", the text would still be in the input box, i.e. would have maintained the state.

Is this not the case, and if not, is there a way to maintain state in forms on pages which the user navigates away from?

**home.htm**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>{{subtitle}}</p>
</div>
<input ng-model="message"/>
```

**index.htm**

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <style type="text/css">
            [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
                display: none !important;
            }     
            a:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>    
    <body ng-cloak ng-controller="mainController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">AngularJS Routing</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>        

        <script>
                            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
                            mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                                $routeProvider
                                        .when('/', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
                                            controller: 'mainController'
                                        })
                                        .when('/about', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/about.htm',
                                            controller: 'aboutController'
                                        })
                                        .when('/contact', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.htm',
                                            controller: 'contactController'
                                        })
                                        .otherwise({
                                            redirectTo: '/'
                                        });
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.subtitle = 'the home page';
                                $scope.message = '';
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.subtitle = 'the about page';
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.subtitle = 'the contact page';
                            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Controllers do not maintain state, they are created and destroyed every time you go through the route.  You will need to implement a service that you can use to store your data and then have a means to send the data to the service when you want to persist it.  Controller have a '$destroy' event that occurs right before the scope is released that you can hook.

```
mainApp.service('myData', function() {
  this.message = '';
})
.controller('mainController', function($scope, myData) {
  $scope.message = myData.message;

  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    myData.message = $scope.message;
  });
});
```